# How to completly restore a Edit menu in Cocoa or find missing Actions like Redo

Tags: cocoa, menu

I deleted the Edit menu from my cocoa app but now I need to restore it with all the voices. I tryed to copy it from another app but it lose all the Actions... so I found myself with all the voices of the menu but they do nothing... so I started to connect all the voices in First Responder and it was working but then I noticed that some voices like "Redo" and others are not in First Responder and I don't know where to find them..
Is there a way to completly restore the Edit menu in my app? or if it is no possible anyone knows where I can find the missing Actions like Redo?
Thanks for any help - Peace - Massy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the Interface Builder Object Library (Where there are buttons and other controls to drag onto your interface.)

There you will find `Edit Menu Item`. (Search for it if you can't see it.)  You can drag it into your menu.

Comment: Thx a lot for your help! Peace - Massy